# HttpClient. Default credentials to authenticate on auto discovered proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, credentials, dotnet-httpclient

Control freak disclaimer: yes, there are a lot of questions about HttpClient and proxy, but they use at least one of

- explicite (non default) proxy credentials
- explicite (non WPAD) proxy configuration
- deprecated Api, e. g. WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy, WebRequest and so on.

According to [dotnet developers](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7037#issuecomment-198535967)

> if the default value of HttpClientHandler.Proxy is null, then HttpClientHandler will use IE proxy settings

So to set right corporate proxy with HttpClient we don't need any additional actions, just

```
_client = new HttpClient()
```

And there is no official way to get the proxy selected.
But how can I pass default AD credentials to authenticate on auto discovered proxy then?
I just receive "(407) Proxy Authentication Required."

P.S. Possibly there is another problem and running as a service under special account (especially on Linux) this code have no IE setting to use. So we need to re implement WPAD.

Comment: What is your `dotnet --version` of the machine that gets the 407 response?

Comment: @StevenLiekens Currently my service compiled to .Net Framework 4.5 which is presented on server. It has no dotnet utility. Still would be nice to get idiomatic answer covering .Net in essence not specific old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass credentials to a default system proxy using code like this with HttpClient:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: So as before .Net 4.7 `HttpClientHandler` has no `DefaultProxyCredentials` property, I should use `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` to create `WebProxy` and then configure his credentials?

Comment: Oh, I've found! Earlier 4.7 we need `<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" ><proxy usesystemdefault="true" autoDetect="true"/></defaultProxy>` in app.config. Now it's clear.

Comment: Actually, for pre 4.7, you can do this:

    WebRequest.DefaultWeb.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: @David-MSFT, guess you meant WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials ... (WebRequest.DefaultWeb does not exist).

Comment: the app.config of @Serg seems to work too. Took me some time to figure out the right syntax. The defaultProxy node has to be nested inside the <system.net> element.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings